# Finding minimum value of a set of numbers in a column vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, minimum

I am trying to find minimum value of a set of numbers in a column vector which is part of a matrix. More specifically, if I have a matrix as follows,

```
 1 2 3  4  2.7
 7 2 3  8  2.3
 5 2 3  9 12.5
10 4 5 12  1.1
11 4 5 13  5.6
14 5 6  7  1.2
15 5 6  8  0.5
16 5 6  9  3.4
17 5 6 12  6.8
```

then, I would like the output to be as follows,

```
 7 2 3  8 2.3
10 4 5 12 1.1
15 5 6  8 0.5
```

I thought about dividing the matrix based on whether columns 2 and 3 are same, and then finding the minimum value of column 5 in every sub-matrix, but I wasn't able to implement it effectively. (Edit: What I tried to do, I first separated the 2nd and 3rd columns of the matrix (say, A), then I used *unique* to get number of occurrences of repeating rows as follows,

```
      A_dup = A(:,2:3)
      [A_uni,~,u_id] = unique(A_dup,'rows')
      num_occur = histc(u_id, unique(u_id))
```

The vector 'num_occur' will tell me how to divide the matrix A in sub-matrices. This is not much, but I was stuck after this.)

If there is a better way to do it, I would be glad to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the matrix based on the elements of the 5th column using [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) and get the indices of the sorted elements. Find the row subscripts of the [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) rows of the 2nd and 3rd columns of the new matrix . Use these row subscripts with the indices found before to get the row subscripts to be kept from the original matrix. [`Sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) them to maintain the order. Use the sorted new row subscripts to get the required result.

```
[req, idxA] = sortrows(A, 5);           
[~, idxtmpA] = unique(req(:,2:3), 'rows');
req = A(sort(idxA(idxtmpA)), :);
```